# Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web - don't generate bin and obj folders

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Can I turn off generating these folders on build? They contain some .dll, .pdb and other files I don't need. I'm just using Typescript compilation.

Comment: If you create an ASP.Net project you need those dlls. If you don't need some you can delete them or use the Nuget package manager for some. If you only use Visual Studio for TypeScript IntelliSense and use the generated file in another project you can individually open the file and not create a new project

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. I relied on the following nice overview on how to hijack a build process: 
http://sedodream.com/2013/06/01/HijackingTheVisualStudioBuildProcess.aspx

Three main tricks:

1) project_name.csproj is the one you need to modify, it is XML MSBUILD file.

2) You cannot remove dependency from WebApplication.targets, you need to "deactivate" them as below.

```
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

3) You have to implement general contract for clean/build/rebuild targets.

Mine looks like:

```
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Exec Command="call node_modules\.bin\tsc.cmd src/main.ts --out js/game.min.js &gt; $(Temp)\tscout.txt" IgnoreExitCode="true" WorkingDirectory="$(SolutionDir)" />
    <Exec Command="type $(Temp)\tscout.txt" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Rebuild" DependsOnTargets="Clean;Build">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Clean">
    <RemoveDir Directories="js">
    </RemoveDir>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a New WebSite instead of New Project. That one should not create any binary output.
[image]